# NER Dataset For Phone Number

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to make NER dataset For phone numbers like '**+44 (0)845 257 0422**',

i have a tags of phone numbers detected by regex. when i am trying to sentence tokenizer and then word tokenizer, the phone number splits. so i am not able to match this phone with the tag 
anyone have idea to make a number as one word without splinting by nlp.

```
def custom_tokenizer(nlp):
infix_re = re.compile(r'''[.\,\?\:\;\...\‘\’\`\“\”\"\'~]''')
prefix_re = compile_prefix_regex(nlp.Defaults.prefixes)
suffix_re = compile_suffix_regex(nlp.Defaults.suffixes)
return Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, prefix_search=prefix_re.search,
                            suffix_search=suffix_re.search,
                            infix_finditer=infix_re.finditer,
                            token_match=None)
```

i tried this function so it only work for hyphen **239-734-1608** the numbe is not split.
i am looking for solution for this number **+44 (0)845 257 0452**

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. You have a word tokenizer that is correctly able to identify numbers of type XXX-XXX-XXXX as a single token but fails on numbers having brackets and plus signs as it splits them. And your aim is to be able to identify both number formats as a single token. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: word tokenizer has not correctly able to identify numbers. numbers having space, brackets and plus signs as it splits them.and yes my  aim is to be able to identify whole  number as a single token.